# How to make a constraint use the view with highest height from an array of views

Tags: ios, snapkit

Let's assume I have 4 views, 3 in a row and 1 in another row. The ones at the first row have dynamic height and we have no idea how tall they are.

I want to achieve the result from this image:

[image]

Basically I want to set View 4's top to bottom of highest view in first row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `greaterThanOrEqualTo`:

```
view4.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
view4.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
view4.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view3.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `View1`, `View2` and `View3` inside `UIStackView` (or regular `UIView`), and then add constraint between `bottom` of this `new view` and `top` of `View4`